# Using URLEmbeddedView to get OG Data

Tags: swift, github

So I'm trying to fetch open graph data from websites. Luckily I've found [URLEmbeddedView](https://github.com/szk-atmosphere/URLEmbeddedView), but I'm having problems with it.
I added it to my pods and installed it, but from what I understand it is not fetching anything.

What works in the git example:

```
extension OGSampleViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    guard let urlString = searchBar.text else { return }
    print(urlString)
    embeddedView.loadURL(urlString) {
        if let _ = $0 {
            return
        }
        OGDataProvider.sharedInstance.fetchOGData(urlString: urlString) { [weak self] ogData, error in
            if let _ = error {
                return
            }
            let text = "- sourceUrl        = \(ogData.sourceUrl)\n"
                + "- url              = \(ogData.url)\n"
                + "- siteName         = \(ogData.siteName)\n"
                + "- pageTitle        = \(ogData.pageTitle)\n"
                + "- pageType         = \(ogData.pageType)\n"
                + "- pageDescription  = \(ogData.pageDescription)\n"
                + "- imageUrl         = \(ogData.imageUrl)\n"
                + "- createDate       = \(ogData.createDate)\n"
                + "- updateDate       = \(ogData.updateDate)\n"
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self?.textView.text = text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

In my example I cut it down a lot in order to understand it and make it work:

```
import URLEmbeddedView
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()    


class LinksViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

let urlString = "https://google.com/"

OGDataProvider.sharedInstance.fetchOGData(urlString: urlString) { [weak self] OGData, error in
                if let _ = error {
                    return
                }

            let text = "- pageTitle = \(OGData.pageTitle)\n"

            self?.textView.text = text
        }
    }

 }
```

The result of the textView is:

[image: nothing]

I'm fairly new to Swift, so my question is if that is the proper way of using providers? I don't get any errors while compiling, but clearly there is something wrong in using this.

Answer (score 1):

In URLEmbeddedView exist class `OGData`, your code looks like You are tring to use it. Just rename your variable to same as in example - `ogData`. Try this:

```
import URLEmbeddedView

class LinksViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    let urlString = "https://google.com/"

    OGDataProvider.sharedInstance.fetchOGData(urlString: urlString) { [weak self] ogData, error in
            if let _ = error {
                return
            }

        let text = "- pageTitle = \(ogData.pageTitle)\n"

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self?.textView.text = text
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ogData and OGData are the same, there is a line (not shown here) which sets them equal. I tried that already. --Edit: Actually you might be on to something, ogData is undeclared for me, but it shouldn't.

Comment: Did You check it when You dispatch setting textview to main queue?

Comment: In which method do You call above code? `viewDidLoad` or something similiar?

Comment: Yes true in viewDidLoad, I added it to the question.

Comment: Did You set `NSAppTransportSecurity`?

Comment: I didn't, that's new to me. But I also checked and I don't get an error which says that would be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it actually does work in principal, just not the pageTitle and some of the other parameters in the first code sample above. I just checked the same code again for all parameters, and some of them are just nothing:

[image]